# How to save data as a video file with python

Tags: python, video, saving-data

I have been able to transmit video data in h264 format over a socket and now I want to be able to save it as an h264 video file. I tried doing this with

```
file  = open("Filepath.h264", "wb")
file.write(videoData)
```

but that just saves it as a text file. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: You used the "wb" parameters write the .h264 file, the data in the "videoData" will be convert to bytes data.

Comment: What about the resulting file makes it a “text file”?  Also, does the source stream already contain start codes?